# How to show resized image OpenCV imshow()

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

I have a 3000x4000 image and I am using the following code:

```
import cv2 as cv
im = cv.imread ('we.jpg', cv.IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION) # So the image appears in horizontal
cv.imshow ("", im)
```

And the image opens up to a real scale, which prevents me from visualizing it in its entirety (only a piece of the image is visible).

Is there any way to see the scaled image in such a way that it can operate with its dimensions but when it comes to viewing it, it looks whole? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make a copy of the image when you want to view it & [resize the copy prior to showning it](https://learnopencv.com/image-resizing-with-opencv/)

Comment: yeah of course I did that but the problem is that I have to do some other things with that image after the displaying, so I would need to keep the real dimensions.

Comment: just recopy the results for display everytime you something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just say: `cv.namedWindow("thewindow", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)` (before corresponding imshow calls)

That makes the window resizable.

Add the WINDOW_OPENGL flag if you want the window to use linear interpolation (which may or may not be gamma-aware...). Some GUI backends normally use nearest neighbor "interpolation" (win32 for example).

Comment: This is great :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```py
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

down_scale = 4

dir = sys.path[0]
original = cv2.imread(dir+'/im.png')
h, w = original.shape[:2]

small = cv2.resize(original.copy(), (w//down_scale, h//down_scale))
cv2.imshow('Small Image', small)

# Do whatever you like here.
# For example, you found the coordinates on
# the small image and now you want to find
# it on the big image.

positionOnSmallImage = (10, 10)
positionOnLargeImage = (10*down_scale, 10*down_scale)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```